# Attachment not getting set on visualforce on salesforce sites

Tags: salesforce

I have created a visualforce page which has attachment upload feature.
The attachment gets uploaded under a custom object invoice.

Now this page is accessible to internal users using tab and also available publicly on salesforce sites.

Upload feature work perfect in salesforce instance, but when uploading the attachment on sites, the attachment variable does not set.

here is the snippet: (Not complete code)

```
<apex:outputPanel id="AddAttachmentinner">
    <div class="slds-form-element">

        <label class="slds-form-element__label">Select Relevant Attachment:</label>
        <br/>
        <apex:inputFile title="Choose File" value="{!filebody}" filename="{!filename}" />
        <br/> Please select only pdf, xls, doc, jpg, tiff, png type of files

    </div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

```
public pagereference SubmitInvoice(){
    public String filename {
            get;
            set;
        }
    public Blob filebody {
            get;
            set;
        }
    public Attachment attachment {
            get;
            set;
        }

    if (filebody != null && filename != null && filename != '') {
        attachment.Name = filename;
        attachment.Body = filebody;
        attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        attachment.ParentId = newInvoice.Id; // the record the file is attached to
        attachment.IsPrivate = false;
        upsert attachment;
    }

}
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: Are you certain you've set appropriate permissions for your object? Is the Site User valid as an OwnerId? Are you certain you have an Id value for your newInvoice record? Have you checked the log in the developer console? Just throwing out ideas that I would check. If you plop a `apex:pageMessages` tag just under `apex:page` you may get some error message back from the server, too.

Comment: Hey @Peter thanks for coming back. To be sure, i inserted a dummy filename and blob in attachment variable in controller and it worked. Its just attachments not setting up while using inputfile tag. Am i missing something here?